# Count of likes on a post through Wordpress Rest API

Tags: wordpress-rest-api

I want to get the count of likes on a post in wordpress using wp-json/wp/v2/posts/{post_id} REST API. Could not find anything related on stckoverflow or anywhere else.

I tried some plugins like jetpack but they are used to add like button below the post. I want to get the number of times a post has been liked through REST API